# Mac OS X Defaults How to pass the current date?

Tags: macos, shell, plist

I have trying to run the below script to modify the timestamp in the Growl plist but the script is unable to update the plist.
If I execute the same thing from the command line then it works fine.

Please help.

```
#!/bin/sh
current=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000"`
cmd="defaults read com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp LastUpdateCheck -date '$current'"
echo $cmd
`$cmd`
echo `defaults read com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp LastUpdateCheck`
```

Comment: The third line would make more sense if it said defaults write ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the command in a variable, the quoting doesn't work the way you think it does (see [BashFAQ #050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).  (And BTW the `echo $cmd` is not telling you what command will actually be executed).  Just run the command directly.

Also, I presume you're trying to run `defaults write ...`, not `defaults read ...`.  Finally, the echo and backquotes on the last line effectively cancel each other -- just remove both.  Here's what I get:

```
#!/bin/sh
current=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000")
defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp LastUpdateCheck -date "$current"
printf "New value of LastUpdateCheck: "
defaults read com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp LastUpdateCheck
```

If, for some reason, you actually do need to store the command in a variable before executing it, use an array.  But note that this is a bash-only feature, so start the script with `#!/bin/bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %l:%M:%S +0000")
cmd=(defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp LastUpdateCheck -date "$current")
printf "About to execute:"
printf " %q" "${cmd[@]}"  # Need to use printf trickery to get appropriate quoting
printf "\n"
"${cmd[@]}"
printf "New value of LastUpdateCheck: "
defaults read com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp LastUpdateCheck
```

Comment: Thanks,it works like a charm. By the way, I have used the first approach.